# Whether pose values returned by laser_scan_matcher package relative or cumulative

Tags: ros, pose, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was referring to a tutorial pertaining to [laser_scan_matcher package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher). Nevertheless, I have one question regarding this package. It publishes pose2D topic which comprises of position(x, y) and orientation(theta).

Are those position and orientation values *cumulative* or *relative*? *Cumulative* in the sense that, if we have 3 state values for one state variable, say x, then, the third state value is actually the result of the *integrating* those previous two state values. On the other hand, *relative*, I mean in the sense that the third state value is obtained with respect to the second state value.

Hopefully someone who is familiar with this package can clarify on this.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12266/whether-pose-values-returned--by-laser_scan_matcher-package-relative-or-cumulative/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In that sense, they are cumulative

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-08**:
@Ivan Dryanovski : Thanks a lot, very sorry to keep on asking you..I just wanted to be sure about it. That helped a lot..

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-12-08**:
yes, thats correct

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-08**:
@Ivan Dryanovski: They are cumulative including orientation, right?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-08**:
@Ivan Dryanovski: Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-29**:
@Ivan Dryanovski: could you please have a look at this: http://answers.ros.org/question/28781/using-laser_scan_matcher-output